# wildcard search in FileSensor airflow

Tags: python, shell, airflow

I have a file path as

```
fpath = "/path/abc20200216"
```

where date after abc keeps changing every month.

Now I want to use this in FileSensor

```
file_sensor = FileSensor(task_id= "file_sensor_job", poke_interval= 30, filepath = fpath, run_as_user='xyzzy',dag=dag)
```

how can I pass a wildcard keyword in the Operator.

Or is there any other alternative for sensing file in remote server using airflow?

Answer (score 1):

As of this [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/5358/commits/e93a87f628f1a0db2d3838be3036532e11fa25f8) You could pass a file blob to filepath for FileSensor.

For eg:

```
prefix = 'abc'

fileblob = os.path.join(os.path.dirname('/path/'), prefix +'*')

file_sensor = FileSensor(task_id= "file_sensor_job", poke_interval= 30, filepath = fileblob, run_as_user='xyzzy',dag=dag)
```

You could also take a look this test [case](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/4d03e33c115018e30fa413c42b16212481ad25cc/tests/sensors/test_filesystem.py#L126) from Airflow repo

Comment: it doesn't seem to work. It appends the path and filename and hence my job is looking for something like this: /path/abc* .I am not sure why is it specifically looking for file abc* while it should have also fetched abc12, abc20200216, etc.

Comment: what is your airflow version ?

Comment: Version : 1.10.7

Comment: I'm also facing this issue where wildcard matching is not working in FileSensor. Did anyone find solution or workaround for this?